# Replacing &nbsp; with white space in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, whitespace

From my REST API, I am passing in certain strings where white space is replaced by a white space.

When it comes to the handlebars component, I would like to replace these back with whitespace before it is displayed in the browser.

How can I replace a part of a string, white space, in this case, with   inside of the handlebars.

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <table>
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#goalSetValues}}
            <td><button onclick=init('{{goal}}')>{{goal}}</button></td>
        {{/goalSetValues}}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function init (goalName) {
        console.log('came inside the init function with goalName == ' + goalName)

    }

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

I have tried a couple of things,

```
<td><button onclick=init('{{goal}}')>{{replace goal " " "&nbsp;"}}</button></td>
```

and

```
<td><button onclick=init('{{goal}}')>{{#replace "&nbsp;" " "}}{{goal}}{{/replace}}</button></td>
```

However, they do not seem to work. Please advise me.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, the browser is already able to render &nbsp; as a space

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, exactly what I hoped. But the html of my page shows &nbsp;. Say one of the values in my goalSetValues array is, Hello&nbsp;World, it displays as, Hello&nbsp;World on the html page. For this reason, I am looking to replace the &nbsp; with whitespace

Comment: Try triple {{{brackets}}} to output raw

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, looks like that works, shall try a few more scenarios and respond.

Comment: Great, I will transfer my comment to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use triple brackets: `{{{}}}` to output as raw HTML.

Then the `&nbsp;` will automatically be rendered as whitespace by the browser.

E.g.

```
<td><button onclick=init('{{{goal}}}')>{{{goal}}}</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your goalSetValues array in such a way so as to replace the **"&nbsp ;"** in your string with an actual non breaking space.

`var string = "Hello&nbsp;World";
var nbsp = String.fromCharCode(parseInt("00A0", 16));
string = string.replace("&nbsp;", nbsp);`

This will make the string "Hello World" but the space you see is actually a non breaking space.

Comment: thanks for the response. However, my html translates to <td><button onclick=init('Hello World')>Hello World</button></td>. I am unable to call the init function upon onclick with a parameter that has a white space. That is the crux of the problem, and I am trying to get around it by replacing space with &nbsp;, so it is a single string without whitespace. Please suggest a better alternate approach, if any.

Comment: Okay. But you need to understand the difference between a normal  whitespace and this non breaking space. The both look the same but behave differently. For example, if I have a normal "Hello World" in which there is a normal whitespace and the output you would get by using the code above would look the same but aren't. If I do string.split(" ") above , even then I would still get "Hello World" because you are splitting on a normal whitespace but actually you have a non breaking space. So by tweaking your logic a bit, I don't think it will be too much of a change for you.

Comment: Part 1/2 : @Behram, I guess I don't really understand. I have a value from my backend API which has spaces, and I need to pass on to the front end. This value needs to create a button of the same name, with the whitespaces, and also call a function upon onclick, with the same name, with whitespaces. I am able to display with whitespaces, but when I try to call the onclick function, it breaks since it does not allow whitespaces as part of a parameter. My idea was to replace the space in the backend api, with &nbsp; and pass along, hoping the html would display as a white space, and I get to

Comment: Part 2/2 : pass a value without any whitespaces inside my onclick function, since I have replaced the space with &nbsp; and I can replace it back inside my function, if needed. What are you suggesting I should do? Seems to be something different from what I am thinking